# CMake ExternalProject: how to specify relative path to the root CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: git, build, cmake, build-process, build-automation

It seems that CMake [`ExternalProject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) always assumes the root directory
of the external project to be the source directory. But what if that is not
the case?

Consider the following example:

The external project uses this directory layout:

```
libfoo.git                 <--- ExternalProject assumes this as source dir.
├── ...
└── libfoo                 <--- However, the actual source directory is this!
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └──  ...
```

In the depending project `libfoo` is configured like this:

```
ExternalProject_Add( libfoo 
    PREFIX            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/EP_libfoo"
    GIT_REPOSITORY    "<link to remote which hosts libfoo.git>" 
    GIT_TAG           "<some hash>"
)
```

The build then fails with the following error message:

```
$ cmake -H/path/to/source-dir -B/path/to/build-dir
...
$ cmake --build /path/to/build-dir/ --target all
...
CMake Error: The source directory "/path/to/build-dir/EP_libfoo/src/libfoo" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
...
$
```

So, as pointed out in the above directory layout, CMake thinks that the root of
the external project is

```
/path/to/build-dir/EP_libfoo/src/libfoo
```

when, in fact, it is

```
/path/to/build-dir/EP_libfoo/src/libfoo/libfoo
```

My attempts to solve this problem:

1. Unfortunately, changing the argument `SOURCE_DIR` of `ExternalProject` did 
   not work, because the value of this variable is used as the location to 
   which the git repository of `libfoo` is cloned into. This results in a recursive dependency hell which cannot be broken.
2. Changing the directory layout of `libfoo` to comply with `ExternalProject`.
   Obviously, this would work but it might not work for other (read-only) 
   third party libraries.
3. Abusing the update/patch step of `ExternalProject`, e.g. by specifying

   ```
   set( EP_LIBFOO_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/EP_libfoo" )

   ExternalProject_Add( libfoo 
       PREFIX            "${EP_LIBFOO_DIR}"
       GIT_REPOSITORY    "<link to remote which hosts libfoo.git>" 
       GIT_TAG           "<some hash>"

       # Copy the content of `<...>/libfoo/libfoo` into `<...>/libfoo`.
       # Note to self: using symlinks instead copying is too platform-specific.
       PATCH_COMMAND     ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${EP_LIBFOO_DIR}/src/libfoo/libfoo" "${EP_LIBFOO_DIR}/src/libfoo"
   )
   ```

   This works but it's hackish and very prone to fail with other external projects.
4. Building on the [solution to another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27574747): add a temporary 
   `CMakeLists.txt` in the location where CMake assumes it. This temporary file
   then includes the actual `CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   set( EP_LIBFOO_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/EP_libfoo" )
   set( GENERATED_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated" )

   file( MAKE_DIRECTORY ${GENERATED_DIR} )
   file( WRITE ${GENERATED_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt
       "cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )\n"
       "add_subdirectory( libfoo )\n" 
   )

   ExternalProject_Add( libfoo 
       PREFIX            "${EP_LIBFOO_DIR}"
       GIT_REPOSITORY    "<link to remote which hosts libfoo.git>" 
       GIT_TAG           "<some hash>"

       # Copy the 
       UPDATE_COMMAND    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/CMakeLists.txt ${EP_LIBFOO_DIR}/src/libfoo
   )
   ```

   This works as well and feels better than the previous solution.

However, does a *more elegant* exist to do the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've submitted [a merge request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/63) to add a `SOURCE_SUBDIR` option to `ExternalProject_Add` that will solve this use case. Hopefully it will be available in CMake 3.7. (You can also copy `ExternalProject*.cmake` locally into your own project to take advantage of the feature immediately.)

Comment: The feature was accepted and is available as of CMake 3.7: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html

Answer (score 3):

You can simply overwrite *cmake* command ant set path to the *CMakeLists.txt* manually. For example

```
ExternalProject_Add(libfoo
   PREFIX            "${EP_LIBFOO_DIR}"
   GIT_REPOSITORY    "<link to remote which hosts libfoo.git>" 
   GIT_TAG           "<some hash>"
   CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G${CMAKE_GENERATOR} "${EP_LIBFOO_DIR}/src/libfoo/libfoo")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SOURCE_DIR /path/to/build-dir/EP_libfoo/src/libfoo/libfoo
```

ExternalProject_Add call. That designates the actual source directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible and it was the first thing I tried (see 1. in the question). In your example the git repository is cloned into `/path/to/build-dir/EP_libfoo/src/libfoo/libfoo`. And now I would like CMake to use `/path/to/build-dir/EP_libfoo/src/libfoo/libfoo/libfoo` (3x libfoo) as the path to the root CMakeLists.txt (it's a sort of cyclic dependency)

Comment: Just a quick update: provided that I cloned the repository of `libfoo` *manually* I could use your suggested solution (instead of specifying `GIT_REPOSITORY`). Maybe that's what you meant. However, manually downloading dependencies is not really an option since it's too error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with the same issue in a project that I am working on and this is the solution I have been able to come up with.  It results in not using ExternalProject for the git handling but results in the same behavior as far as I have been able to tell.

CMakeLists.txt

```
include(ExternalProject)
set(libfoo_prefix ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/libfoo)

# during generation remove any previous repo and clone.
file(REMOVE_RECURSE ${libfoo_prefix})
execute_process(
    COMMAND git clone <link to remote which hosts libfoo.git>
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY})

# Add the external project.
ExternalProject_Add(libfoo
    PREFIX ${libfoo_prefix}
    SOURCE_DIR ${libfoo_prefix}/libfoo)
# As part of the pre-build step update the git repo.
add_custom_command(
    TARGET libfoo
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P GitPull.cmake)
```

GitPull.cmake

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND git pull origin master
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/libfoo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution

```
set(EXTERNAL_PROJECTS "")
set(EXTERNAL_LIBS "")
include(ExternalProject)

# Set compiler(s) per project as required to CMAKE_ARGS in ExternalProject_Add(..).
#       -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
#       -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
set(EXTERNAL_CMAKE_ARGS -D CMAKE_SYSROOT=${CMAKE_SYSROOT}
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM}
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY}
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE}
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE}
)

set(AIOUSB aiousb)
set(AIOUSB_SRC aiousb_src)
set(EXTERNAL_PROJECTS ${EXTERNAL_PROJECTS} ${AIOUSB_SRC} ${AIOUSB})
set(AIOUSB_SRC_GIT_BRANCH "master")

ExternalProject_Add(${AIOUSB_SRC}
    PREFIX ${AIOUSB_SRC}
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/accesio/AIOUSB.git"
    GIT_TAG ${AIOUSB_SRC_GIT_BRANCH}
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${AIOUSB_SRC}/src/${AIOUSB_SRC}/AIOUSB/CMakeLists.txt
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

set(AIOUSB_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${AIOUSB}/src/${AIOUSB}-build/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}${AIOUSB}${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
set(AIOUSBCPP_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${AIOUSB}/src/${AIOUSB}-build/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}${AIOUSB}cpp${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})

ExternalProject_Add(${AIOUSB}
    DEPENDS ${AIOUSB_SRC}
    PREFIX ${AIOUSB}
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${AIOUSB_SRC}/src/${AIOUSB_SRC}/AIOUSB
    CMAKE_ARGS ${EXTERNAL_CMAKE_ARGS} -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
        -DBUILD_SAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_AIOUSB_SHARED:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_AIOUSBDBG_SHARED:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_AIOUSBCPP_SHARED:BOOL=OFF
        -DBUILD_AIOUSBCPPDBG_SHARED:BOOL=OFF
    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib/include/${AIOUSB} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${AIOUSB}/src/${AIOUSB}-build/lib/libaiousb.a
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${AIOUSB}/src/${AIOUSB}-build/lib/libaiousbcpp.a
    INSTALL_COMMAND rm -rf ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib/include/${AIOUSB} && mkdir -p ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib/include/${AIOUSB} &&
        echo "ln -sr ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${AIOUSB_SRC}/src/${AIOUSB_SRC}/AIOUSB/lib/*.h ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib/include/${AIOUSB}" | bash
)

set(LIBAIOUSB libaiousb)
add_library(${LIBAIOUSB} STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ${LIBAIOUSB} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${AIOUSB_LIBRARY})
add_dependencies(${LIBAIOUSB} ${AIOUSB})
set(EXTERNAL_LIBS ${EXTERNAL_LIBS} ${LIBAIOUSB})

set(LIBAIOUSBCPP libaiousbcpp)
add_library(${LIBAIOUSBCPP} STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ${LIBAIOUSBCPP} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${AIOUSBCPP_LIBRARY})
add_dependencies(${LIBAIOUSBCPP} ${AIOUSB})
set(EXTERNAL_LIBS ${EXTERNAL_LIBS} ${LIBAIOUSBCPP})

...
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXTERNAL_PROJECTS})
...
also add 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXTERNAL_LIBS} ...)
```

Basically you break it into two parts. The first just to get the source and the second to buld the software. I manually create links to the headers so kdevelop's parser does not have to parse the entire project.

Answer (score 1):

For those, who still looking for an answer: try to specify `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`:

```
ExternalProject_Add(libfoo 
    GIT_REPOSITORY "<link to remote which hosts libfoo.git>" 
    GIT_TAG "<some hash>"
    SOURCE_DIR "where to put the source"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND
        "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
        "-HPathToDirectoryWhereTheCMakeListsAre"
        "-BWhereToBuild"
    BUILD_COMMAND
        "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build "Path to the directory where you are building (specified with -B flag in CONFIGURE_COMMAND)"
)
```